# Look for where code fails

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, methods

see this HTML markup:

```
<input value="9961" name="c_id" id="c_id" type="hidden">
<input name="user_id" id="user_id" value="1" type="hidden">
<textarea id="comments" name="comments" style="width: 310px; resize: none; height: 75px"></textarea>
```

Then I write this code in jQuery to send this data through .post:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 220,
    width: 350,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function () {
            if ($('#comments').val() != '') {
                $.post("<?php echo site_url('wall/comment') ?>", {
                    value: $("#comments").val(),
                    user_id: $('#user_id').val(),
                    c_id: $("#c_id").val(),
                    is_post: true
                });
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $(location).attr('href', "<?php echo site_url(); ?>");
            }
        },
        "Cancelar": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        $("#comments").val("");
    }
});
```

But for some reason isn't working but because I use `.post` method I can't find where it fails meaning if is jQuery or if it's the server side part.

**EDIT**
This is the PHP code that gets data and run the queries that basically is a INSERT:

```
    public function comment() {
        role_or_die('wall', 'comment', site_url(), lang('wall:no_permissions'));

        $message = $this->input->post('value', TRUE);
        $post_id = $this->input->post('c_id', TRUE);
        $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id', TRUE);

        $this->load->library('user_agent');
        $device = "";

        if ($this->agent->is_browser()) {
            $device = $this->agent->browser();
        }

        if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
            $device = $this->agent->mobile();
        }

        if ($this->wall_comment_m->insert(array('friend_id' => $user_id, 'message' => $message, 'post_id' => $post_id, 'device' => $device))) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', lang('message:comment_add_success'));
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', lang('message:comment_add_error'));
        }
    }
```

I can't see if the SQL generated is the mistake or if data isn't set at server side because of the location.href.

How I can find where it fails? Any method or something tool to get this done?

Comment: In PHP, use `var_dump($_POST);`. This will tell you what is passed into the PHP script via POST.

Comment: What "isn't working".  What does the code currently do?

Comment: Just for info, it's HTML code, and your <textarea> block isn't valid to W3C specs, old IE browser don't supported "height" and "width", you must replace this by "cols" and "rows" attributes, Also, can you add your Javascript( jQuery) code in your sample?

Comment: Whoops, didn't mean to delete MaxArt's first comment. For reference, it was: "Why don't you post your PHP code? It could be very helpful."

Comment: @MichaelMyers and others I edited the post with PHP code, sorry for that I miss to published before

Comment: @DocRoms: Pretty sure it's valid in HTML5.

Comment: @DocRoms Hmmm it's HTML5 valid but I use other libraries like Modernizr to get this work in old browsers and our lovely IE ;) and also I write this properties as CSS, notice the style tag, and I think this is pure CSS and not a input tag property so should works anyway thanks for your suggestion

Comment: The title is unbelievably useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.post` is asynchronous.  That means that it runs in the background.

So, the `$(location).attr('href', "<?php echo site_url(); ?>");` will run *before* the POST finishes.

You need to use `$.post`'s callback.

```
var that = this;
$.post("<?php echo site_url('wall/comment') ?>", {
    value: $("#comments").val(),
    user_id: $('#user_id').val(),
    c_id: $("#c_id").val(),
    is_post: true
}, function(){
    $(that).dialog("close");
    $(location).attr('href', "<?php echo site_url(); ?>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks to you and your suggestion I can see now where it fails, is a DB problem with one column. I was reading something about the callback but didn't know how to use in this profile until now. Many thanks to you and all others